# excel converting the string to scientific notation

Tags: python, excel

is there way to prevent data exported from python to be converted into the scientific notation in excel.

```
ID
1E1
2E9
3E4

After exporting in csv format iam getting: 
ID
1.00E+01
2.00E+09
3.00E+04
```

I found a similar thread however none have a clear explanation or links were broken.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows how you are using the CSV module to write these values.

Comment: Put a single quote `'` at the front of each string in your CSV file.

Comment: I think it's issue of column format in Excel.

Comment: @pepoluan it's not just the output format - Excel is converting the value from a string to a number when it reads it.  This is a well known weakness of using Excel for CSV files.  You either need to use the import process which allows you to assign a type for each column, or somehow format the value so Excel keeps it as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the issue with Python writing the wrong value in CSV file. If you open the csv file, you will see value is written in correct numeric format. If that is not the case, please provide your code and sample data.

Assuming it is written correctly in CSV using python, then Please look for converting the values in excel from scientific notation to text or number.